# Perform function on specfic date(s)

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum

Is it possible to have a soldity smart contract perform a function on a predefined date (E.g. perform a payment on 2/12/2018) without requiring an external events to call the function? If yes, how would this look like in solidity?

Comment: I think it is possible. I have read something about that. If you google it you may find some librairies.

Comment: There is not and there's no plan to support such feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not and there's no plan to support such feature.

Contracts themselves cannot be the `tx.origin`, because currently every transaction must be originated from an account. You might want to remodel your application so you don't have constantly update its state.

Some examples:

- You can make every call to the contract update its state, executing jobs if conditions are met
- Use withdraw model if you want to send funds to users after a deadline

  - Many contracts use this model, including ENS
- You can make a function to update the contract state. Then you call this function yourself every `n` blocks.

  - SmartBillion uses this model to save the block hashes of blocks that are more than 256 blocks behind